# Can't remove open logical volume

Tags: lvm

When I try to remove a logical volume I get the message

```
#lvremove /dev/my-volumes/volume-1 
Can't remove open logical volume "volume-1"

#lvchange -an -v /dev/my-volumes/volume-1 
Using logical volume(s) on command line
/dev/dm-1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
Deactivating logical volume "volume-1"
Found volume group "my-volumes"
LV my-volumes/volume-1 in use: not deactivating

#lvremove -vf /dev/my-volumes/volume-1 
Using logical volume(s) on command line
/dev/dm-1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
Can't remove open logical volume "volume-1"

#lvs
/dev/dm-1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
LV              VG           Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
volume-1        my-volumes   -wi-ao  50.00g
```

How can I force the removal of this volume?

Thanks,
Everett

Answer (score 17):

What does the logical volume contain? Is it a filesystem (I accidentally wrote partition)? Could it be it's mounted? In that case:

`umount /dev/my-volumes/volume-1`

Does it have any active snapshots?

Edit: try `lvchange -an -v /dev/my-volumes/volume-1` and `lvremove -vf /dev/my-volumes/volume-1`.

Edit 2: please post 'lvs'.

Edit 3: Try this with some other problematic volume. It's not the cleanest option but according to [this site](http://slashzeroconf.wordpress.com/2008/07/11/lvm2-remove-or-deactivate-problem/) it may work, and it's less problematic than rebooting anyway.

```
dmsetup remove my--volumes-volume--number
lvremove /dev/my-volumes/volume-number
```

Comment: It doesn't contain anything. It's not a partition. It's not mounted (any longer). No active snapshots.

Comment: Well, what did you use it for? It may give us a clue as to what may be wrong.

Comment: Added the info you requested to the question. It was being used as a volume for OpenStack Compute (aka Nova). I actually managed to remove it by going nuclear and rebooting the machine and then doing an lvremove. Way more drastic than I wanted to be. I still have some other volumes hanging around that I would like to get rid of without having to reboot so any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I've added something for you to try with some other problematic volume.

Comment: Tried it. No luck. I also tried everything from http://wiki.davidjb.com/blog:unix:removing-open-logical-volumes-in-centos-rhl (hence the "/dev/dm-1: read failed..." in some of my output) but that didn't work either.

Comment: What about running `udevadm control --stop-exec-queue` before trying the `lvremove`? https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=577798

Answer (score 16):

If you are unable to unmount or lvremove a logical volume, verify that there are no processes holding the LV

Locate the major/minor numbers for the logical volume you’re trying to remove eg:vol0

```
# dmsetup info -c | grep vol0
```

Take note of the 5th column, which indicates if a volume is “open,” and the 2nd and 3rd columns, which are the major and minor IDs, respectively.

Find any process attached to this volume by searching on the major and minor IDs discovered above:

```
# lsof | grep "major,minor"
```

Shut down or kill any process still accessing the volume to continue unmounting and removal.

then try lvremove

Comment: In my case no help. lsof, fuser do not show any usage. dmsetup says device is busy. device is unmounted (can be mounted at any time). only a hardware reboot helps :/

Answer (score 8):

I got into similar situation, but removing of LV was blocked, because I was using `mount -o` bind.

[This article](http://kb.eclipseinc.com/kb/why-cant-i-remove-a-linux-logical-volume/) helped a lot, using `lsof` with major/minor numbers of LV showed processes holding opened LV, in my case `smbd`.

`lsof | grep "major,minor"`

Than just simply `cat /proc/mounts | grep LV_name` led me to conclusion, why `lvremove` or `dmsetup` refused to get rid of the unmounted LV.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have iet or tgt running (which one depends on what your `iscsi_helper` value is in /etc/nova/nova.conf, defaults to iet), and the service has an open filehandle. You can check which one by doing something like this (in my case it's tgt)

```
# fuser /dev/nova-volumes/volume-00000001
/dev/dm-5:           19155

# lsof | grep /dev/dm-5
tgtd      19155            root   12u      BLK              252,5         0t0    2531554 /dev/dm-5
```

If it's iet, stop the service by doing:

```
service iscsitarget stop
```

If it's tgt, stop the service by doing:

```
service tgt stop
```

You should then be able to delete your volumes.

Comment: This solved the problem for me with OpenStack

Answer (score 4):

I have traced down some of possible reasons which can prevent one from removing an (seemingly) unmounted LV with no clues in `mount -l`, `lsof`, `dmsetup ls --tree`.

**It can happen because either `mount --rbind` or `systemd-nspawn` were used!**

**How do diagnose**: `grep -l <OLD MOUNT POINT> /proc/*/mountinfo`
If it shows something, then those processes are somehow poisoned with now unmounted filesystem. In my case those were some systemd guts and other services, like systemd-oomd, irqbalance and other. I did `systemctl restart ...` for them one by one and at some point got my firefox killed somehow, so be wary about unwanted side effects. But I managed to get my LV released this way, and I managed to remove it successfully.

I repeat, the stuff from `/proc/*/mountinfo` does not always shows in `lsof`.

Answer (score 2):

Shutdown the LXC containers that use the filesystems via their config : lxc.mount.entry

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to remove `lvm`, then please follow these steps:

1. unmount the Partition:

   **# umount /dev/sda8**

   (eg. I have mounted the partition on `/dev/sda8`)
2. try to remove `lvm` like so:

   **# lvremove /dev/vgname/lvname**

If you get an error like "*can't remove open logical volume in linux*", then try to deactivate the LVM through below commands and then remove it:

```
 # lvchange -an  /dev/vgname/lvname

 # lvremove /dev/vgname/lvname
```

Let us know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with a LV that comes from 3 PVs on an iSCSI device (with multipathing).

No solution worked but a simple **reboot**! (**comment it out in fstab**, so it don't get mounted again)

Maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) in a container, and this seems to prevent the removal of any block devices which were mounted when it started. My fix was:

1. Unmount the LVM volume
2. Restart the cAdvisor container (`docker restart $CONTAINER_ID`)
3. Attempt removal again

Answer (score 0):

this also might be locked by nfslock service in RHEL, just stop that service and the you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
The lv I tried to remove was a VM block device, holding a volumegroup.
This volumegroup was filtered in lvm.conf, but some dev mapper items were created earlier.

To figure out was is hold by a device, look at its minor number (253, **??**)
`ll /dev/<vg>/<lv>` should point to `../dm-??`

Then `ls -la /sys/dev/block/253:??/holders` will give you links of vg (ex `-> ../../dm-xx` ) relaying on your device (as a pv)

Remove them with `dmsetup remove /dev/dm-xx` (make sure that those dm are not used)
Then you should remove /dev// which is no more a "pv" somewhere

Comment: Im My case this is `dmsetup remove /dev/dm-36` but i get the error
`device-mapper: remove ioctl on vg0-snap--tmp--vm06.docker--disk failed: – Device or resource busy –
Command failed` see: https://serverfault.com/questions/926681/kill-a-process-inside-an-lvm-snapshot

Answer (score 0):

You may unlink your LV from the DM device:

## fuser -kuc /dev/my-sample-volumes/volume-sample-1

/dev/dm-21:           2400ce(root)  2739ce(root)  4793ce(root)

## ls -l /dev/my-sample-volumes/volume-sample-1

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 15 02:53  /dev/my-sample-volumes/volume-sample-1  -> ../dm-21

## unlink /dev/my-sample-volumes/volume-sample-1

## lvremove /dev/my-sample-volumes/volume-sample-1

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't think `lvremove` is going to work after `unlink`, could you clarify that part? Just edit your answer.

Comment: It should work. I've tested it. It will just unlink to its softlink. the LV should be still existing and you may remove it with lvremove.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem and none of the solutions here worked. Indeed it might be NFS holding up your LV, in this case fuser or lsof won't show you any open files to your mount point, so just check if your NFS server is running with

```
# systemctl | grep -i nfs
```

or

```
# ps -aef | grep -i nfs
```

and check if the nfs service is exporting the mount point once related to your device with

```
# exportfs -v
```

If so just remove it or comment it from /etc/exports

Restart or stop nfs server with

```
# systemctl restart nfs
# systemctl stop nfs
```

or

```
# service nfs restart
# service nfs stop
```

You'll be able to issue your lvremove command after this.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as yours. I tried the following command and resolved:
swapoff -a

lvremove ...

Comment: that could lead someone to blindly try your command. Better to just point out, if LV is used for swap, then swapoff the lv first, and only this, not just -a